# How to index data in single solr app using tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I am working on single solr app. I downloded solr exampple code for net, which is working fine while running on jetty server.It is having data which are to be indexed in C:\apache-solr-1.4.0\example\exampledocs and the indexes are stored in C:\apache-solr-1.4.0\example\solr\data, using jetty server indexes are created using command java -jar post.jar *.xml. Now i want to know how can i achieve this using Tomcat. do i need to change the configuration to change the path for indexe storage and for xml files storage. how data will b indexed so that i would able to search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solrconfig.xml you can mention the path that has to hold the index

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
```

Comment: I have mentioned this in solrconfig.xml, and i also added the java option -Dsolr.data.dir, bt i am really confused when i am deleting <dataDir> from solrconfig.xml still i am able to index the  data..how is it ???

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll want to use the `-Durl` flag when running post.jar, e.g.:

```
 java -jar -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/update post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to read more from SOLR documentation, and click through what you have in the package.

There is an tomcat deployment doc in solr wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

And the war file is in the dist folder you've downloaded.

How to search it? There is no simple answer. I suggest you read more on the solr wiki. Find out what is a handler, what is the difference between dismax handler and standard handler, how schema.xml defines the database.

Comment: @user658991: I am not asking how searching is implemented in solr. i just want to know where it is storing the indexes, what configuration setting i have to change for it.Please reRead the question.